# Android AsyncTask issue: doInBackground does not execute

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I´m using AsyncTasks in my android app.

When i have to set a `Service` (AlarmManager) via `BroadcastReceiver` and get out of the application and reopen the app, the AsyncTask just does not execute.

How can i fix that? What i presume is there´s some threads or tasks not finished, causing this kind of issue.

Comment: Post the code you use to start your AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because as of Honeycomb (and before Donut) [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s are executed serially on a single thread. Do you have any other long running AsyncTasks that may be blocking the new one?

Comment: Yes, i have, and i found the answer! I just did this:
[code]
authenticationTask = new AuthenticationTask(this, String.valueOf(representante.getCodigo()), representante.getSenha(), PedMobileUtils.decrypt(representante.getSenha()));
     
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)       
      authenticationTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);    
      else
       authenticationTask.execute();
[/code]

Comment: Yes, i have, and i found the answer! I just did this, problem solved!

authenticationTask = new AuthenticationTask(this, String.valueOf(representante.getCodigo()), representante.getSenha(), PedMobileUtils.decrypt(representante.getSenha()));
     
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)       
      authenticationTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);    
      else
       authenticationTask.execute();

Thx a lot!

Comment: It seems like my answer was correct (and please mark it as answered). One of your other AsyncTasks was blocking. Your solution is to just use a thread pool which uses another thread. In general, if you want a long running task, you shouldn't use an AsyncTask as described in the AsyncTask documentation.